# Serialize and Deserialize Visual Studio Solution files - or programmatically edit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serialization, projects-and-solutions, deserialization

I wanted to programmatically add and remove projects, solution folders and other items such as resource files to a solution, but I'm not exactly sure what would be the best way to go with that.

For those that don't know, highly simplified; this is how a sulution file (.sln) normally looks like:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "project name", "projectpath\name.csproj", "{785ECC80-AF1B-4FBC-B97B-2EC43B7E81E8}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {785ECC80-AF1B-4FBC-B97B-2EC43B7E81E8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

I'm not sure if this is an actual open standard such as xml (it is?), but it kind of seems like the visual basic team made its own version of xml. (not a compliment)

So anyway, what would be the best way to serialize and deserialize this to and from objects? I was thinking about making my own IFormatter, but that seems rather complex.

Comment: What about using a Visual Studio Macro?
The Macros allow you to automate nearly every available command in the VS IDE.
I wouldn't edit the sln/prj files as the format changes slightly with every VS version.

Comment: For now I only need to be able to edit vs2010 solution files. And I don't think a Visual Studio Macro will do, I'm going to need to for an actual class library.

Comment: If you can be sure that a VS IDE is available on the executing machine you can open a VS IDE in the background and automate your tasks via the DTE interface. See http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/mz2005005.aspx

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: @Kiquenet unfortunately not. I ended up writing my own parser

Answer (score 4):

## Using EnvDTE library:

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3dys0y2.aspx) `EnvDTE is an assembly-wrapped COM library containing the objects and members for Visual Studio core automation.` You can also find there documentation of [`Solution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solution.aspx) and [`Project`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx) interfaces with using examples which should be very helpful.

## Without EnvDTE library:

**Solution file:**

It seems there isn't a lot to do here - adding a project and setting build configuration. In my opinion the best approach would be to parse it using simple TextReader and rewrite it after adding some data. This is the template.

`Project("{solution guid}") = "project name", "projectpath\name.csproj", "{project guid}"`

Remember to use the same solution guid in every project.

**Project files:**

No surprises here, it is standard XML file which you can create/modify using LINQ to XML. Whole specification with examples is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx. Of course 
Don't forget to use the same project guid like in solution file.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code:

```
        using EnvDTE;
        .....

        Solution s = new SolutionClass();
        s.Open(solutionFilePath);
        s.AddFromFile(projectFilePath);
        s.Remove(s.Projects[6]);
```

You can navigate projects as in `foreach(var project in s.Projects)` and check their `project.Name` property to find the one you want.

Add to references following dll (AddReference->Browse tab):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\EnvDTE.dll.

All classes are pretty well documented in MSDN. EnvDTE is very powerful library for VS autoamtion, you can do much more then add/remove. I would not bother serializing sln file myself, I agree it was bad to invent own formating.

Comment: That does not seem to work: 
Error 1 The type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' has no constructors defined
Error 2 Interop type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' cannot be embedded.

Comment: I believe it should be var s= EnvDte.Dte.Solution