# Programatically add ressource file to ANOTHER project

Tags: c#, resources, resx

I need to create resource files (.resx) programatically. Those ressource files are meant for
other projects, not for the one where I programatically create those resx files.

Is there a clean way to tell the other solutions/projects that it has to add the externally created ressource file.
In the resoure files strings are stored which shall be used in that project later.

Example:

I create a Resource.resx file with a project called ResourceCreator.
Now I have to tell a Project called MyProject to bind it into the solution/project WITHOUT to have to manually open the solution and add it then.

Comment: At what point are you planning to do this? Run-time?

Comment: No all projects should be closed when the resource is added. So I need a way to edit the solution and tell it to include the external created resource file. And when I open the solution it should be visible and of course usable for the project.

Comment: Think I foudn something useful to edit existing solutions EnvDTE library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3dys0y2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe you really want to create [Satellite Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> A satellite assembly is a compiled library (DLL) that contains
>   (“localizable”) resources such as strings, bitmaps, etc. You are
>   likely to use them when creating a multilingual (UI) application.
>   Satellite assemblies provide you with the capability of designing and
>   deploying your solution to multiple cultures, rather than hard coding
>   strings, bitmaps, etc., into your main application. Satellite
>   assemblies are used to deploy applications in multiple cultures (not
>   languages), with 1 satellite assembly per culture - this is the
>   default behavior, but you can obviously have more granular control if
>   you handle the build process manually.

[MSDN Ref - Introduction to Satellite Assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the `Microsoft.Build` namespace, it has all sorts of fancy ways of loading/modifying project and solution files.

[Microsoft.Build namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145008.aspx)

Comment: Looks better, found here on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064675/serialize-and-deserialize-visual-studio-solution-files-or-programmatically-edi - EnvDTE library

Comment: Also useful, true, but be careful: if you have to deploy the code using this, I'm not entirely certain if the dte libraries are redistributable